# response.body() result changes during execution. (retrofit2-get method)

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm a beginner learning Android.
I'm trying to make my application receive data from local database.
So I used retroit2 as followed

```
public class SNSDataServicer {
    private String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/";

    Retrofit retrofitClient =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

    SelectAPI select = retrofitClient.create(SelectAPI.class);
    InsertAPI insert = retrofitClient.create(InsertAPI.class);
    UpdateAPI update = retrofitClient.create(UpdateAPI.class);
    DeleteAPI delete = retrofitClient.create(DeleteAPI.class);
}

interface SelectAPI{
    @GET("sns/all/{candidate}")
    Call<List<SNSData>> selectAllByCandidate(@Path("candidate") String candidate);
}
```

and this is the code for MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SNSDataServicer dataService = new SNSDataServicer();
    List<SNSData> snsDataList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView checker = findViewById(R.id.checker);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dataService.select.selectAllByCandidate("3").enqueue(new Callback<List<SNSData>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<SNSData>> call, Response<List<SNSData>> response) {
                        snsDataList = response.body();
                        return;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<SNSData>> call, Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("Failure", "onResponse: Failed");
                    }
                });

                if(snsDataList==null) {
                    checker.setText("null");
                } else {
                    checker.setText(snsDataList.get(0).getMedia());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**When I press button, the textview's text should be set to size of the list.
But snsDataList kept on returning null
eventhough reponse.body() returned list successfully**

below is scree capture of my debugging.

1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSo0e.png)

by this point it was perfect, but when I hit F8 to debug next step

2. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO2CB.png)

response body has been changed and when I hit F8 more, it takes me to

```
ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java
Handler.class
Looper.class
```

and no more.

Then suddenly my snsDataList becomes null...

This is ridiculously hard for me and I've tried to solve it by myself for very long but I have failed...
Can someone help me with this problem? It will be really grateful.